# Django memory Leakage/ less worker

Tags: python, django, machine-learning, memory-leaks, backend

I am working on a project where I have to integrate ML and django together. when running the app there is some lag in compiling and after several minutes i am getting this:

UserWarning: A worker stopped while some jobs were given to the executor. This can be caused by a too short worker timeout or by a memory leak.

what is it? how can i solve this?

The project should have fetched the data from datasets and then compare the user input and show the result.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Without knowing where that warning came from (where is that worker pool? Inside Django?) It is hard to say what is happening. You say your app has 'some lag in compiling', what are you compiling? Native modules?

Answer (score 0):

the warning related to the Gunicorn worker process that is handling your Django application and indicates that the gunicorn worker has stopped processing tasks while some tasks were still in the queue. this can happen when a worker time out is short or when there is a memory leak within the application

to increase the worker timeout in gunicorn configuration file you can set the "timeout" parameter to higher value:

```
gunicorn --timeout 120 myproject.wsgi:application
```

examine you application for any memory leaks, memory leaks can cause the application to consume excessive memory that leading to a worker crash. you can use tools like `memory_profiler`or django's built-in memory management tools to find any memory leaks in your code.

also you check your code for loops or operations that might be causing a bottleneck and optimize your code

if these don't help consider upgrading the resources on your server

I hope this helps you